# Spring: How do I substitute constant values for constructor-args?

Tags: java, spring

I am working on a project where I am given a project configuration as

**project-config.xml**

```
 <bean id="awsCredentials" class="com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials">
        <constructor-arg
                value="${com.myorg.sparrow.s3EnvironmentConfiguration.S3EnvironmentConfigurator.dest.ProposalManager-accessKeyId}"/>
        <constructor-arg
                value="${com.myorg.sparrow.s3EnvironmentConfiguration.S3EnvironmentConfigurator.dest.ProposalManager-secretAccessKey}"/>
    </bean>
```

I am adding a test configuration from where I can pass this values

**test-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    com.myorg.sparrow.s3EnvironmentConfiguration.S3EnvironmentConfigurator-destBucketName=bucketname
    com.myorg.sparrow.s3EnvironmentConfiguration.S3EnvironmentConfigurator.dest.ProposalManager-accessKeyId=accesskey
    com.myorg.sparrow.s3EnvironmentConfiguration.S3EnvironmentConfigurator.dest.ProposalManager-secretAccessKey=secretaccess key

    <bean id="spa-evaluation-factory" class="com.myorg.sparrow..business.DummySpaEvaluationFactory"/>
    <import resource="classpath:/com/myorg/sparrow/spa_adapter/project-config.xml"/>
</beans>
```

But this doesn't work. How can I

have the variables defined in `test-config.xml`

```
com.myorg.sparrow.s3EnvironmentConfiguration.S3EnvironmentConfigurator-destBucketName=bucketname
        com.myorg.sparrow.s3EnvironmentConfiguration.S3EnvironmentConfigurator.dest.ProposalManager-accessKeyId=accesskey
        com.myorg.sparrow.s3EnvironmentConfiguration.S3EnvironmentConfigurator.dest.ProposalManager-secretAccessKey=secretaccess key
```

substitute for values in `project-config.xml`

```
<bean id="awsCredentials" class="com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials">
            <constructor-arg
                    value="${com.myorg.sparrow.s3EnvironmentConfiguration.S3EnvironmentConfigurator.dest.ProposalManager-accessKeyId}"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way, your place holders should get resolved.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/test.properties" local-override="true" properties-ref="localProperties" ignore-resource-not-found="true"/>

<util:properties id="localProperties">
    <prop key="com.myorg.sparrow.s3EnvironmentConfiguration.S3EnvironmentConfigurator-destBucketName">bucketname</prop>     
    <prop key="com.myorg.sparrow.s3EnvironmentConfiguration.S3EnvironmentConfigurator.dest.ProposalManager-accessKeyId">accesskey</prop>        
    <prop key="com.myorg.sparrow.s3EnvironmentConfiguration.S3EnvironmentConfigurator.dest.ProposalManager-secretAccessKey">secretaccess key</prop>     
</util:properties>
```

Another way would be to have the entries in the test.properties file above.